# Замена HDD RAID 1 на более ёмкий HDD [windows]

Tags: windows, raid

Есть система Windows 10 которая стоит на Software Raid 1 встроенными средствами Windows. Какими способами можно заменить все HDD в RAID 1 на более ёмкие? Короче говоря, нужно перенести систему с Software RAID 1 500G на Software RAID 1 1TB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Простой вариант - через полный бэкап. Геморройный - заменять по одному диску, а потом растянуть раздел(ы).

Comment: т.е. делаем образ системы на внешний HDD, ломаем RAID, создаем новый RAID с новыми HDD и накатываем систему?

Comment: Зачем ломать-то? просто снимаешь старые харды. Они, кстати, ещё и выполнят роль "второго бэкапа" на случай, ежели что пойдёт не так...

Comment: А как в случае с mdadm не получится сделать? Вставить два других HDD, подождать пока они синхронизируются, вытащить старые и увеличить размер RAID?

Comment: Т.е. в промежутке создать четверное зеркало, из 4 дисков? ну можно и так... хватило бы каналов на контроллере да мощи блоку питания...